# Фигурные скобки без условия/цикла

Tags: c

Всем привет и заранее спасибо за потраченное время. 
Вопрос касательного вот такого участка кода:

```
// Register callback ...
FuncCall();

// Commemt
{
    VOID *Param3;
    static GUID Param1 = ENTER_GUID;
    static EVENT Param2;

    RegisterProtocolCallback(
        &Param1 , InitRomIfr,
        NULL, &Param2, &Param3
    );
}

if(){...}  '
```

а именно - **Как фигурные скобки (только они, без условия) применяются в коде?** Использование фигурных скобок после условия/цикла я ещё понимаю, а вот с использованием фигурных скобок без условия я не сталкивался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фигурные скобки - это блок кода. А это дает сразу много преимуществ.

- переменная, определенная в таком блоке будет жить до завершающей скобки
- удобно для RAII - контроль за временем жизни (к примеру, файл будет закрыт или мютекст разлочен)
- в случае использования switch/case, каждый case удобно дополнять фигурными скобками для локализации кода.

В принципе, если посмотреть на тот же if или for, то они используются так `if(<условие>) <выражение>`, а что бы можно было в качестве `<выражение>` использовать более одной строки кода как раз и нужно использовать блок. То есть, if/for,  у которого тело за заключено в скобки это не особенность оператора.